# How to execute a callback in the original thread in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

In C++, can I execute a function in a thread, and pass to this function a lambda that will be executed in the original thread ?

```
class A
{
    void fA()
    {
        // thread 1
        boost::thread t(boost::bind(&A::fA, this, [=]() { /* code to execute in thread 1 */  }
    }

    void fB(const std::function<void()> &callback)
    {
        // thread 2

        how to execute 'callback' in the original thread (thread 1) ?
    }    
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could consider using a thread safe queue implementation like [this](https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/concurrent-queue-c11/). You pass the queue as an argument when the thread is created, then wait on it in the original thread. When your callback is called you just push onto the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot arbitrarily run code on another existing thread that is carrying its own business. As @bames53 stated on his answer, you need some cooperation mechanism with this thread to deliver tasks to it, like a queue or some place you will place this task.

Example:

- Thread 1 creates tasks and place them on queue;
- Thread 2 fetch tasks from queue and execute them;

Note that allowing two concurrent threads to modify variables shared among them is a very dangerous practice, and will most likely cause crashes. To do that safely, you must use mutex (mutual exclusion), a technique that guarantees that the threads won't access a shared variable at the same time.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I note this one as the 'correct' one because of "You cannot arbitrarily run code on another existing thread".

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
void thread1() {
  boost::thread t(blah, ... whatever);

  while (true) {
    std::cout << "working\n";
  }
}
```

The thread that's spawned here can't just interrupt the thread that created it and make it start executing whatever the spawned thread wants. If a context is not responsible for spawning a thread and therefore setting the thread's 'entry point', then getting the thread to run some code requires cooperation from the thread itself.

For example, a thread might continuously process a queue of work items. Getting such a thread to run code just depends on putting a work item into the queue.

So if you want background threads to be able to come back and make some code execute on the original thread you need to design the original thread to allow this. Generally this is done as described above with a queue of some sort. A couple examples of this are the Windows Event loop or `dispatch_main()` in GCD on OS X.